# Should I use multiple Lucene directories/indexes to search different types of data?

Tags: java, mysql, lucene, full-text-search

I have many MySQL tables to store different types of data like goods, catagories, brands, suppliers, etc. Each of them needs to implement full-text search via Lucene.

So I plan to build one Lucene Directory (and one IndexWriter + one IndexReader corresponding to this Directory) for each table, e.g.

```
HashMap<String, Directory> = ...;
put("goods", FSDirectory.open(luceneDirRoot + "/goods"));
put("catagories", FSDirectory.open(luceneDirRoot + "/catagories"));
...
```

Is this a good practice to use Lucene?

Furthur more, how can I know how many directories I made by Lucene, like MySQL command "SHOW TABLES"? `new File(luceneDirRoot).listFiles()` can be a choice but I am not sure whether there are other non-Lucene folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement one Lucene index pro MySQL table provided you do not need to perform search over several tables. Alternative would be to write everything into one index and add table name into each lucene document, that way you could limit the search to particular table.

AFAIK Lucene does not support SHOW TABLES equivalent the way you desire it, but you might easily do that by yourself, e.g. by using naming convention for the directories.

I would recommend to look at Hibernate Search, this is a good match for your needs, it builds one index directory pro table and allows you to perform full text search while handling the low-level lucene issues for you. You just configure the index by annotating the JPA entities corresponding to your tables and have to implement the full text queries. This is much easier then doing naked Lucene with data from MySQL on your own, Hibernate Search builds the index for you and integrates well with data from relational DB such as MySQL.